Why is Excel suddenly showing leading quote/apostrophe when opening a CSV? This apostrophe trick recommended by Microsoft seems to no longer work
Our application generates CSV files, which are typically opened by users in Excel. In order to format a certain column as "Text", we prefixed values with a single quote/apostrophe (eg instead of outputting 123, our application output '123). For many years this has worked without issue.
FWIW, we use this trick to  output a large number into a CSV that when opened in Excel will display as-is, not in scientific notation. This trick is recommended by Microsoft at the bottom of this page.

Use the apostrophe character
You can type an apostrophe (') in front of the number, and Excel will treat it as text.

However recently our users have noticed that the leading apostrophe is now displaying when they open these CSVs in Excel. This is easily reproduced:

Create a file my.csv in Notepad with content:
'1
'2


Open my.csv in the latest version of Excel (I'm using Version 2410). Note that the leading apostrophes are now displayed:


Select a cell and click in the Formula bar. Press Enter. This will cause the apostrophe to be hidden.



Has there been a recent change to Excel that has caused this? And is there a way to not show these apostrophes (without having to hit Enter in every cell or change the column data type)?

@Ramhound I am on Windows using version 2410 build 18129.20158 (File -> Account - version number displayed next to "About Excel")

Having tried it on a different system, I was able to confirm that this issue does exist. I suggest rolling back to an earlier Office build.

@Ramhound, I would still consider this as exploiting a  bug as it is open to interpretation what it should be converted to

I have gone as far back as the Oct build of Office, and it doesn't work there. The documentation likely just has not been updated.
